# get position vector in mips

Tags: assembly, mips

I am having difficulty performing a code that must perform the following task:

```
int m = (first + last) / 2
if (value == v[m])
return v[m]
```

what I am doing is the following:

```
add $ t5, $ t1, $ t2    # m <- first + last
li $ t6, 2              # assist division
div $ t5, $ t6          # m / 2
mflo $ t5               # m = result

lw $ t7, v ($ t5)       # 
beq $ t7, $ t3, return  # value == v[m] return
```

My problem is that `lw $ t7, v ($ t5)` is not working.
Any solution?!

Comment: _"is not working"_ is a poor problem description. You should clarify exactly what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having spaces between the `$` and the register name looks like a typo, but maybe your assembler allows that.

If the elements in your array are words - as they seem to be, since you're using `lw` - then they will be 4 bytes apart. So you need to multiply your index by 4 to get the correct address. This can be done using the `sll` instruction:

```
sll $t5, $t5, 2   # $t5 <<= 2 == $t5 *= 4
```

By the way, it's unnecessary to use `div` when you're dividing by a power of 2. You can use `srl` instead (or `sra` if you want a signed division):

```
srl $t5, $t5, 1   # $t5 >>= 1 == $t5 / 2
```

You can read more about bitshift operations [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts).

Comment: Hi, yes spaces between the $ error was of like a typo.